# How can I use javascript, html and css to make an image a button, which can do the following?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When it is clicked, it should open a drop down menu, containing links.
Please provide the full code as well.
Here is the code for the image/button that I have:

```
<div class="navBar">
<img src="nav_icon.jpg" class="navButton" alt="Navigation Links">
<div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#">Home</a>
 <a href="#">Get Involved</a>
    <a href="#">About Us</a>
    <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS part (which isn't really relevant:)

```
.dropdown-content{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);

}
.navButton{
    height:20px;
    width:20px;


}
.navBar{
    float:right;
    height: 10px;
    width:20%;
    padding-top:4.2%;
     position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I've tried the following example, which instead of creating what I want, makes all the links appear:
[W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp)

Comment: Good luck with that.

Comment: Is that supposed to imply its not possible? I tried an example from w3 schools but it does not work.

Comment: No, sorry I mean you're in the wrong place if you're asking for a complete solution to a problem with no existing half working attempt of your own. *Please provide the full code* is not a type of question we like to answer here.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Have you researched the scenario?

Comment: Thanks, that's a good start. Can you add the CSS and JavaScript you tried as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `HTML` that you have provided, If you compare your markup with [W3School's Example](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp), I see two problems that are causing your menu not to work properly. I've listed them below:

1. There should be an `id` attribute on drop down menu.

   `<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">`

   ```
     // ^^^----- This id attribute should be added.
   ```
2. You forgot to add click event handler on `.navButton` that will toggle drop down menu each time it is clicked.

   `<img src="nav_icon.jpg" class="navButton" onclick="myFunction()" alt="Navigation Links">`

   ```
                                          // ^^^ Add this inline click handler
   ```

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.navButton')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
/* Dropdown Button */
.navButton {
  height:20px;
  width:20px;
}

/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */
.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */
.show {display:block;}
```

```html
<div class="navBar">
  <img src="nav_icon.jpg" class="navButton" onclick="myFunction()" alt="Navigation Links">
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Get Involved</a>
    <a href="#">About Us</a>
    <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, your post solved this problem. But now for some reason when I change the setting to "float:right;" it is being displayed just next to the logo. I have a fixed header, logo on the left and the button on the right. Why is this happening?

Comment: @YousufFarhan Can you make a fiddle of your code. I't will be helpful to identify problem with more precision.